# Database schema for large possible product combinations and associated price

Tags: database-design, mariadb, schema

I'm new to database schemas and need some help.

I have to draw up a database schema from a large, (2601) possible product combination, with width and height and associated price.

Is creating columns form all the combinations the correct way?

Comment: Could you gives to us more information about your needs? Such as what do you want to perform, what you already got, and what obstacles you have.

Comment: And maybe give some example data. Give us contrived data examples of real data is too industry-specific for us to understand.

Comment: Apologies for the little information. This was the first time posting to this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is creating columns for all the combinations the correct way? Based on the little information you have given us: No, columns for all combinations is probably not the right solution. Imagine if you suddenly get more products, then you will need to add more columns. Or if some products are removed. Designing your schema so you have to alter a table to deal with something as trivial is bad practice. No, you should probably use records instead.

Let's say you have a `combination` table, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE combination (
  combination_id int unsigned auto_increment,
  product_id int unsigned,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (combination_id),
  CONSTRAINT combination_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (product_id) 
    REFERENCES product(product_id)
);
```

So you will insert a record for each product in a certain combination.

You can then select from this table, and join with your product table, to get a listing with all the combinations where a certain product is involved:

```
SELECT c.combination_id, p.product_name, p.width, p.height, p.price
FROM combination c
  JOIN product p USING(product_id)
WHERE p.product_id = 56
ORDER BY c.combination_id, c.product_id;
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! Apologies for the little information.